# How to integrate spring-xd batch jobs with Control-M scheduler

Tags: spring-batch, cloud-foundry, job-scheduling, spring-xd

I'm trying to solve integration between Control-M scheduler and batch jobs running within spring-xd.

In our existing environment, Control-M agents run on the host and batch jobs are triggered via bash script from Control-M.

In the spring-xd architecture a batch job is pushed out into the XD container cluster and will run on an available container. This means however I don't know what XD container the job will run on. I could pin it to a single container with a deployment manifest, but that goes against the whole point of the cluster.

One potential solution.

Run a VM outside the XD container cluster with the Control-M agent and trigger jobs through the XD API via a bash script. The script would need to wait for the job to complete, by either polling for the job completion via the XD API or wait for an event to signal the completion.

Thinking further ahead this could be a solution to triggering batch jobs deployed in PCF.

Answer (score 1):

In a previous life, I had the enterprise scheduler use Perl scripts to interact with the old Spring Batch Admin REST API to start jobs and poll for completion.

So, yes, the same technique should work fine with XD.

You can also tap into the job events.

Comment: Thanks Gary. Think I just need to dive into it and try it out. Signalling completion of the job back rather than polling would be a nice option to have too.

Comment: As I mentioned: `You can also tap into the job events.` See the [XD Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-xd/docs/1.1.2.RELEASE/reference/html/#_retrieve_job_notifications) about using a stream to tap into job events.